# applicationWillTerminate entering the background

Tags: ios, objective-c

having trouble figuring out what happens when an app is terminated.

Looking at the apple docs for applicationWillTerminate it says:

**For apps that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case.** However, this method may be called in situations where the app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

What does it mean by apps that support background execution? Does it mean "backgrounding" has to be enabled in the settings for the app or is it referring to older versions of iOS?

Why does the app enter the background instead of terminating? How long will it remain in the background?

I want to update an object in my Parse backend when the app enters the background, I do this using:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        //End the Task
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if([self getController]){                
            CatsViewController *catsViewController = [self getController];
            if(catsViewController.currentUser){                    
                int count = (int)[MyViewController.currentUser.messages count];
                PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
                currentInstallation.badge = count;
                [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }];                    
            }                
            else{                    
                [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        }            
        else{                
            [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    });
}
```

From the documents it seems it isn't 100% that this will be called when an app is swiped to terminate. If this is the case then how can I save my data?

Comment: Background means. iOS has introduce some functionality which can work in background like "Fetch Device Location" etc..

Comment: So it doesn't mean the app has to have Background App Refresh enabled for the particular app?

Comment: @Kex no; that's just one particular kind of background execution. But you need to be using one of them. Usual questions: what are you actually trying to achieve? The failure to receive `applicationWillTerminate` shouldn't be a problem in any circumstances.

Comment: To enable background process you need to set it up during the development. "I dont know how to do this. but you can get the idea from google."

And also if you are putting background process in your app and upload it for the review for iTunes then apple will review this background process.

Answer (score 2):

From >=ios4 when you press the home button your app goes in a suspended state. That means that the app is not running anymore but it continues to keep occupied a certain amount of the system memory for a fast restore in foreground.
From >=ios4 Apple has introduced real background execution only for a certain type of app, such as: location updates, voices over ip etc. You can have a complete list by looking at project capabilities->background modes. If your app need to work in background it must fit in one of those requirements and you should specify this requirement in your project plist.

Those kind of applications have some privileges. If the system goes short on memory and an app in foreground requires more memory than the amount available, the system first kills the suspended app, if more memory is still needed it can only kills also the applications that are working in background. In this case `-applicationWillTerminate` is called.

This method is also called by apps that doesn't support suspended or background modes.

Comment: so if the app is for >=iOS4 it is safe to say that applicationDidEnterBackground will be called when swiping to quit an app?

Comment: No, this method is called as soon as you press the home button or you fast switch your application with another. The swipe kills the app, but i should be already suspended or in background.

Comment: when I tested it, double tapping and scrolling through aps (but not selecting one) does not call this method but it is called when the app is swiped to kill.

Comment: I know that is confusing but applicationDidEnterBackground is called in both cases of suspended and "real" background app.

Comment: @Kex you are right, I've tried right now, really didn't know about that

Comment: If apps are swiped to kill are they actually put in "suspended" state then, which is why applicationDidEnterBackground is called and then the system then terminates it later?

Comment: I'm using the simulator, maybe on device is different. I really lost my confidence in the app lifecycle, but if you kill the app using the swipe, the app is really killed and not put in suspended state. If you try you can see that on the next relaunch the applicationDidFinishLauching is called instead of willEnterForeground (usually called when an app comes from a suspended state)

Comment: @Kex no, I think Andrea answered a slightly different question; if you double tap the home button then all you do is show the list of apps. If you don't select another one then your app isn't backgrounded. It's still in the foreground. You'll get did enter background only if your app enters the background.